# Clicking uploaded picture goes to the wrong path - .NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, file-upload

I am executing a file upload to the path:

```
C:\Code\Portal\Portal\Files\CT\Test\Test\Lighthouse-2015_07_02_11_46_43_813.jpg
```

But when I click on the file on the website I get a 404 error because it is trying to go to the path:

```
C:\Code\Portal\Portal\Comment\CT\Test\Test\Lighthouse-2015_07_02_11_46_43_813.jpg
```

'Comment' is the name of the controller, but I am trying to get it to go to 'Files' when clicked, which is the name of the folder that holds the picture.

This is the link for the file:

```
<a target='_blank' href="@Url.Action(file.path)">@file.name</a>
```

file.path specifies the path after `'/comment/'`. I am having trouble understanding how to make the comment part of the path disappear. Then I could just add `'Files/'` to the file.path. If I do that now, then the path is `'comment/files'`.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post what `file.path` actually is? and also show us how you are populating `file.path` and your upload code.

Comment: Is `Files` folders internal to the project? Is so use `Server.MapPath("~") + "\Files.....jpg"`. If `item.path` already got the relative path like `Files/....../1.jpg`, then you can use `Server.MapPath(item.path)`,

Comment: The file.path is just the part of the file path starting after the '/Comment/'

Comment: As in it just grabs that part from a database.

Answer (score 0):

- Use PhotoFolder in appSettings of web.config.
- Append the image path to the PhotoFolder path using Path.Combine.
- Create an extension method to UrlHelper called Url.Photo.

Comment: Thank you, I should have specified, but I will be using this for other file types too

Comment: Create an extension method to UrlHelper like MapPath which does what @ramiramilu suggested.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Url.Content](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.content(v=vs.118).aspx#M:System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(System.String)) method. It does a Server.MapPath internally. Url.Action is to get Url for controller action methods.